# Using Keras and Tensorflow to obtain only one prediction for each sample in a database

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a database composed of multiple images from different individuals and I am using keras and tensorflow to predict a quantitative variable. Currently, I am obtaining one predicted output for each image. I want to obtain just one predicted value for each sample. For example, let's say that I have a database composed of 1000 images from 100 individuals (10 images per individual) to predict the height for those individuals, in this scenario, I am obtaining 1000 predicted values of height in my current approach. However, what I really want is to obtain only 100 predicted values of height. I was wondering if the correct approach was to force each batch feed to my model to be composed exclusively of all the images from the same individual (100 batches of 10 images, in the example above). Any comments or suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong here is collating training with how you will use your final model for predictions.

When you train your model, it doesn't matter who the individual is, you should have 1000 images and 1000 height targets (made of up 100 duplicates), so that the training image to training target is 1 to 1.

Once you have a trained the model, if you have this set of data, you can run it 10 times per individual and calculate an average prediction from all of their images.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Currently, it is exactly what I am doing. I am calculating the average of the predictions to estimate the average accuracy. As I have multiple images from the same individual from different perspectives (height, width, and length), I was wondering if I should treat these data structure in a specific way. My concern came after some research about the impact of individual variations in the predictive accuracy and how repeated measures should be treated to reduce this impact. For example, [link](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41746-019-0178-x)

Comment: You could create a model with multiple inputs if you say, for instance, always have images of the front, side and diagonal. You can create three input layers using Keras' [functional API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#models-with-multiple-inputs-and-outputs) and then feed those tensors into a more traditional sequential type model. I could update my answer with some code for that if that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you very much, I think that it is a very good suggestion. I believe that the link that you provided is very well descriptive and I can follow the code to reproduce it in my analysis. However, if I have any issues during that I will accept a suggestion of code to do that. But first, let me try by myself. Thank you very much.